# How to get content page name in user control inside the master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a user control in master page and I need to get content page's name (for example Home.aspx) in user control. Unfortunately I am not getting how to do it. Please guide and help me.

Comment: What do you want to do with this information?

Answer (score 4):

In Page_Load() Event of MasterPage.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

              string strPage = Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath;

        }

    }
```

It will return the child page's virtual path.

Ex: ~/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.apprelativevirtualpath.aspx) property - you can extract the page file name from the virtual path.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Page.Title property.Use it in the page load function

```
string Title = Page.Title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property (say CurrentPage)  in the master or in the base page that returns the current page and refer this from the User Control using

```
 var page ='<%=CurrentPage%>'
```